# How to handle duplicates if the older question (or the answer) is a "subset" of a newer question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, best-practices

I marked this question: [Mac App Store apps damaged?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215279/mac-app-store-apps-damaged) as a duplicate of a newer question [Many OS X app store apps are listed as "app" is damaged and can't be opened](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215332/many-os-x-app-store-apps-are-listed-as-app-is-damaged-and-cant-be-opened).

The reason to do it this way was that the newer question had a more general approach and presented one or more general answer(s) instead of a workaround.

Should I (always) mark the newer question as a duplicate of an older question though the older question is only a special case of the newer one?

Answer (score 2):

The StackExchange developers view and voted up view is if the new question is better then close the old one as the duplicate from this [MetaStackExchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha) (and that makes sense to me) Note this is not exactly your question but the other questions that match yours are closed as dups of this :(

In this case the new question and answer rather obviously are more general and detailed and would be the one that you want to read in the future.

The end result we want is the best question and answer.